# How to upload an image in php with text, resize it and add it to a database?

Tags: php

Here is my solution to the problem that doesn't work. It's made up of four different PHP files one with the form, one to update the database, one to change the image header so it looks correctly and last to display everything.

```
//create form  
<h3>create person</h3>
<form action="create.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
name:<input type="text" name="personname" value=""/>
info:<input type="text" name="personinfo" value=""/>
<br />
<br />
image:<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
</form>

<?php

$people = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people", $connection);


if(!$people){
die("Failed: " . mysql_error());
}

while ($person = mysql_fetch_array($people)){
echo "<h1>{$person["name"]}</h1>";
echo "<p>{$person["info"]}</p>";
echo "<p>{$person["id"]}</p>";
echo "<P>{$person["img_name"]}</p>"; 
echo "<img src=getimage.php?id=" . urlencode($person["id"]) . ">";
echo "<br /><a href=\"Modify.php?personid=" . urlencode($person["id"]) . "\">Modify     User</a>";
echo " ";
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?personid=" . urlencode($person["id"]) . "\">Delete User</a>"; 
 }

?>

//creates image
<?php include 'includes/connection.php'; ?>
<?PHP

$name = $_POST['personname'];
$info = $_POST['personinfo'];
$img_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$size = addslashes($_FILES['image']['size']);
$type = addslashes($_FILES['image']['type']);
$size2 = getimagesize($temp);
$width = $size2[0];
$height = $size2[1];

$newwidth = 100;
$ratio = $newwidth/$width;
$newheight = round($height * $ratio);

$new = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($image);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO people (`id`,`name`,`info`,`image`,`img_name`) 
VALUES (NULL, '$name','$info','$new','$img_name')")or die(mysql_error);
header ('Location: adminarea.php?linkid=1');

?>

//display image
<?php include 'includes/connection.php'; ?>
<?php

$people = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people", $connection);


if(!$people){
die("Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($person = mysql_fetch_array($people)){
echo "<h1>{$person["name"]}</h1>";
echo "<p>{$person["info"]}</p>";
echo "<p>{$person["id"]}</p>";
echo "<P>{$person["img_name"]}</p>"; 
echo "<img src=getimage.php?id=" . urlencode($person["id"]) . ">";
echo "<br /><a href=\"Modify.php?personid=" . urlencode($person["id"]) . "\">Modify          User</a>";
echo " ";
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?personid=" . urlencode($person["id"]) . "\">Delete User</a>"; 
 }

?>


 //change header of image
<?php Include 'includes/connection.php';?>
<?php


$id = addslashes($_GET['id']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = $id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;



?>
```

Comment: Where is the point of failure? Does the query return a result? Is the image stored in a BLOB?

Comment: its probably more efficient to store the image separately and add the path to it to the DB

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).